# Как сделать выпадающий список подстраивающимся под длины элементов?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, select

Есть проблема: элемент `select` фиксированной ширины и, естественно, выпадающий список тоже фиксированный. Требуется его как-то сделать подстраивающимся под длины элементов(только выпадающий список, сам `select` должен оставаться одной первоначальной ширины).

Comment: > сделать подстраивающимся под длины элементов

Под какие элементы?

Comment: Под длину текста в option'ах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То есть, вы хотите, чтоб каждый элемент выпадающего списка имел свою ширину, зависящуюю от текста? Нет, с элементом select, да еще и в восьмом осле это не получится. Можно было бы самому создать псевдо-select, но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: этого и боялся